# More detailed API statistics than The "API Usage last 7 days" report?

Tags: rest-api, api, rest

Recently had an API usage scare and found that the very loose "Day of the Week" column left a lot to the imagination about when that actual day starts. There is no documentation I've found that defines this day's start time.

Hunting around, I see that no Date/Time is available on that report, and there is surprisingly little query-able fields in the database that help in granularly isolating API usage problems.

Am I missing something obvious or are API statistics not readily available?

Comment: Unfortunately, to get more detailed API stats you'll need to use the Event Monitoring module which is an additional cost.  [Here's a Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/event_monitoring/units/event_monitoring_intro) that will give you some info, but you'll have to contact your account executive for details about pricing etc.

Answer (score 4):

If you want detailed API reporting have a look at the Event Monitoring API. While it as a paid feature, it will give you detailed logging about when an API call was made in the corresponding CSV. This includes exact timestamps for when the call occured.

You will likely need a mix onf the [API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm#api), [Bulk API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm#bulk-api), [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm#mdapi-operation), and [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm#rest-api) event types to get a complete picture of all the API calls being made.

See also:

- [Monitoring your Salesforce API usage](http://www.fishofprey.com/2016/06/monitoring-your-salesforce-api-usage.html)